# How to stack/multiply objects or meshes in blender

Tags: modeling

I just wanted to know is there any way to multiply objects, for instance in making rice on plate. you know how they are, random in all direction and piled up at the center, i tried the particle effect and almost all settings, didnt help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to create a mesh, which looks like the 'pile' object. And then on the surface of the mesh, you apply the particles, as a single or grouped rice meshes. Using some randomness in the parameters.

Comment: Please add a more detailed description of how the user is meant to set up the particles.

Comment: Thanks brother, surprisingly, i had the same thought in my dream, I tried it and the results came out as i had imagined, Thanks again :)